# Ufortunately Page has stopped error

Tags: android

I am new to coding just been teaching myself over the last month. Running a project to my phone and get the Unfortunately, Page has stopped error.  There are no red error lines or error codes in gradle build.  I narrowed it down to the image views.  I have three across but when I cut out two it loads fine.  Is something wrong with the "weights".  Here is the codes. (and i know layout and design can be refined just testing design work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boulevard Brewing Company"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view"
        android:id="@+id/logo_view"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:src="@drawable/single_wide_ipa" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:src="@drawable/bully_porter" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:src="@drawable/american_kolsch" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Beer List"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo_view"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:id="@+id/beer_list"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/beer_list"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="80 - Acre Hoppy Wheat Beer"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="American Kolsch"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Berliner Wiesse(seasonal)"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bob's 47 Oktoberfest(seasonal)"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bourbon Barrel Quad"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bully Porter"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bundle Up(limited run)"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cabernet Cask Imperial Stout(limited run)"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Changeling(limited run)"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="City Market Cider(seasonal)"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Collaboration NO.7(limited run)"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />



    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your java or kotlin code too,

Comment: check your logcat error and post it here

Comment: not letting me post the log cat errors says too long.  and the java code is just the basic when you launch a new project.  This is purely to work with the xml design.  Not sure if there is another way to post the log code

Comment: 11-30 12:09:16.945 17919-17919/com.example.jack.brewerypage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.jack.brewerypage, PID: 17919
                                                                              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 32126236 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 29MB until OOM (first part of the fatal error on log cat)

Comment: @JackKaeding see my answer

Comment: android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: i added these two lines from searching outOfMemoreyError.  It worked but way above my paygrade only been doing this one month, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OutOfMemoryError** problem occurred in android while especially dealing with bitmaps. Check your imagees, you are  load too much high in size image in imageview. avoid to use very high-resolution bigsize image.

Rather if you want to use high resolution image  Add `hardwareAccelerated` & `largeHeap` under application AndroidManifest.xml.
 it will work for some environment's.

```
<application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:largeHeap="true"
     android:supportsRtl="true"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Thanks I found that too.  Appreciate the help.  Only been teaching myself for a month so don't understand but it worked.  Thanks for the help.